# xna sound effect failed to load

Tags: c#, audio, xna, monogame

I am having trouble getting XNA sound effect to load. I have tried selecting the file through cwd as well as a full static directory, but when I try to build, the sound effect still reads as null. I have triple checked that the file is in the correct place, as well as that it is included in the project, but it still goes unrecognized.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

namespace Prototype0217
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Color clearColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        SoundEffect noise;
        string cwd = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string ngnl1 = "A:\\DrawingBoard\\Prototype0217\\Prototype0217\\Content\\ngnl1.mp3";

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            noise = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Content\\ngnl.mp3");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// game-specific content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
                clearColor = Color.Green;

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.B == ButtonState.Pressed)
                clearColor = Color.Red;

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.X == ButtonState.Pressed)
                clearColor = Color.Blue;

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Y == ButtonState.Pressed)
                clearColor = Color.Orange;

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.RightShoulder == ButtonState.Pressed)
                noise.Play();
            // TODO: Add your update logic here



            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(clearColor);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With sound effects in particular it's pretty important to process them with the MonoGame Content Pipeline. There's a whole bunch of different file formats that are only supported on some platforms and even within those formats there's variations. In some cases you might even need to convert the file to a different format using another tool.

Comment: @craftworkgames But if the error is with the file format, shouldn't the error be denoting an invalid file format? I've tried mp3, ogg and wav and nothing even changed the error message. The breakpoint still has the value for the noise variable as null

Comment: The code you posted looks like you're not using the Content Pipeline at all. If you where using the Content Pipeline the load line would be `noise = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("ngnl");` without the root path or extension. So possibly, it's not the format but simply not finding the file it's looking for?

Comment: once i got the pipeline working it started working okay. thank you @craftworkgames